# SEO effects of wrapping block-level elements in links

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, user-experience

Sometimes when I am working on a website and the webdesign has something like boxes (online shops' products in grid especially), I tend to hesitate whether to make the whole box a link or not. For example:

```
<a class="product-box" href="/product/123">  
    <img src="/someimage.jpg">
    <h3>My product</h3>  
    <span class="price">1000$</span>  
    <button>See detail</button>  
</a>
```

It seems much more user friendly to me when these box-like elements are whole links, because when on mobile devices, it is harder to hit a small button. However I am not convinced if there's no negative effect on SEO after doing this. It just appears odd to me when a large block of HTML is enclosed in a `<a>` tag.

It is quite hard to find any discussions on this matter so any opinion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [valid in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/), so you're ok to wrap block-level elements in a link. Here's [another article](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links) on the subject.

That said, Google is still on the fence about the practice. According to this thread from the [Webmaster Central Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/HOVcX-hK6hc/discussion), Google's John Mu says:

> That usage [wrapping block-level elements in links] would be fine with us - we'd still pick up the link, and
>   would be able to associate your text as an anchor with that. We're
>   pretty flexible with parsing HTML, so you could probably even use this
>   with HTML4. That said, the clearer you make your anchor text, the
>   easier it is for us to understand the context of the link, so I
>   wouldn't necessarily always use a whole paragraph as the anchor for
>   all of your internal links.

In short, wrapping an entire element in a link makes it hard for Google to understand the context of the link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I was looking for. As I understand that, the best way to achieve what I wanted is to reduce the amount of content (text) inside the hyperlink block to make it easier for Google to understand but keep the box as a link for a better UX.

Comment: That's probably a smart middle-ground approach. Good thinking.

Comment: Don't forget that we can also define a title attribute. MAYBE it could help Google to understand the argument of the page linked. Let's apply this concept to your code: `<a class="product-box" href="/product/123" title="My product"> `.